# Pycharm не сохраняет файлы

Tags: файлы, pycharm

Работаю в pycharm, при сохранении вылетает вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?

Comment: а если проект будет лежать на D диске ошибка останется? И попробуй запустить PyCharm от имени администратора

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])